# Scanf is not waiting for input

Tags: c, timer, signals, posix

I know scanf waits for input. 
But in this program I have written it is printing 
**hello** in an infinite loop. Its not waiting for me to enter.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void timer_handler (int signum)
{
 static int count = 0;
 printf ("timer expired %d times\n", ++count);
}

int main ()
{
 struct sigaction sa;
 struct itimerval timer;


 memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
 sa.sa_handler = &timer_handler;
 sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);


 timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
 timer.it_value.tv_usec = 250000;
 /* ... and every 250 msec after that. */
 timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
 timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 250000;
 /* Start a virtual timer. It counts down whenever this process is
   executing. */
 setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);

 /* Do busy work. 
 */
 int i=0;
 while(1){
    scanf("%d",&i);      //****Not waiting for input****
    printf("hello");   
}
}
```

Output :

```
timer expired 1 times
hello timer expired 2 times
hello timer expired 3 times
hello timer expired 4 times
hello timer expired 5 times
hello timer expired 6 times
hello timer expired 7 times
```

Why ?

?

Comment: Use `scanf(" %d",&i);` instead of `scanf("%d",&i);`

Comment: @rsp Same result.

Comment: @rsp All `scanf()` specifiers, except `c,n,[` first consume leading white-space.  The suggested space  in `scanf(" %d",&i);` serves scant purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scanf` function on POSIX platforms somewhere in its implementation is using the `read` system call. When the timer signal is happening then the `read` call will be *interrupted* and return with an error (`EINTR`), which in turn leads to `scanf` returning as well. You can check this by checking what `scanf` *returns*. In this case it should return `EOF` with `errno` still set to `EINTR`.

A simple solution to this is to ask the signal to *restart* the interrupted system call. This is done by adding the `SA_RESTART` flag in the `sigaction` structures `sa_flags` member:

```
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

More information can be found in e.g. [this POSIX `sigaction` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).

Comment: What is "*it*"? Signals *interrupt* your program, they have nothing to do with threads.