# Using sigaction without SA_RESTART and preventing an infinte loop

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, system-calls

I have the following code:

```
struct sigaction act = {{0}};
act.sa_handler = handler;
sigaction(SIGINT, &act, nullptr);
while (true) 
{
    std::cout << "input:";
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    // Handle line
}
```

When I receive SIGINT, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop. I can't simply set SA_RESTART (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212623/scanf-is-not-waiting-for-input)) because I want to print a message when I receive the signal.

I don't want to print directly from the handler, so I set a flag in it and check it in the loop.

```
if (flag)
    std::count << "got SIGINT" << std::endl;
```

SA_RESTART causes getline to block, so I can't reach this if and handle the signal unless getline returns. Is there anyway around this?

edit(full example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

bool flag = false;

void handler(int signum)
{
    flag = true;
}

int main()
{

    struct sigaction act = {{0}};
    act.sa_handler = handler;
    //act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &act, nullptr);
    while (true) 
    {
        std::cout << "input:";
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);

        if (flag) {
           std::cout << "got SIGINT" << std::endl;
           flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, code that someone else can copy and run to reproduce the problem?

Comment: volatile bool flag = false;

Comment: @ErkiAring This doesn't work. The problem is that getline doesn't block on the next call after getting interrupted by the signal.

Comment: Please don't add the C tag back. C and C++ are different languages and the answer will be different for each. The problem may exist in both as you commented but it does not mean the solution will be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `getline` is interrupted an error flag will be set on `cin`. That needs to be cleared to prevent `getline` from continuously failing.

```
if (flag) {
   std::cout << "got SIGINT" << std::endl;
   flag = false;
   std::cin.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bool flag = false;` is not correct when `flag` is being set by a signal handler.

Correct:

```
std::sig_atomic_t volatile flag = false;
```

See [`std::sig_atomic_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/sig_atomic_t) for more details.